# How to clear a textbox onfocus?

Tags: jquery

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
      $(this).val() == '';
      });
 });
```

Comment: @ $(this).val() == '' you were doing an equality check and as @Jon Erickson says val() is avry handy jQuery function

Answer (score 75, accepted):

To set the value, you have to pass the new value as a parameter. This is a funky thing with the .val() jQuery function.

```
$(this).val('')
```

take a look at the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) and search for 'val'

Comment: They "did it like that" because it's the only thing that remotely makes sense.  What you tried to do isn't an assignment (=) in the first place, it's a comparison (==).  And even if a language supports returning a value from a function that could be assigned to that way, it's a horrible idea; then if you did "var x = $(this).val(); x = 27;" you'd be changing the value of not just x, but your input, in a completely counterintuitive and insanely difficult to debug way.

Comment: Here is an interesting article from James Padolsey regarding getters and setters. He talks about the .val() quirkiness as well http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fun-with-getters-setters/

Answer (score 4):

A little late but another approach would be this

[link text](http://snipplr.com/view/11429/jquery-input-value-select/)

When you click the input box it will select all the text(not clear) only if it is the default value on the box. That way if a user types something then has to go back to edit it, it's not cleared which could be quite annoying!

Also selecting the text instead of clearing it reminds the user of the example. One to keep in mind i guess.