# How to clear text box value when user clicks inside it

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Txt_search" runat="server">Group Name..</asp:TextBox>
```

I want to clear the text inside the text box when user clicks inside the text box to enter the keyword to search.  How do I do that?

Comment: Try this with jquery:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023135/how-to-clear-a-textbox-when-on-focus-with-jquery

Comment: Do you want just pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with jquery:

```
$(function() {

    $('input[type=text]').focus(function() {

           $(this).val('');
      });

 });
```

from:  [How to clear a textbox onfocus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023135/how-to-clear-a-textbox-when-on-focus-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

The script below handles both the `onfocus` and `onblur` events removing your default `"Group Name.."` when focused and adding it back if the user moves off the field without changing anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var txtsearch = document.getElementById("Txt_search");
  txtsearch.onfocus = function () {
    if (this.value == "Group Name..") {
      this.value = "";
    }
  };

  txtsearch.onblur = function () {
    if (this.value.length == 0) {
      this.value = "Group Name...";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery to clear textbox on focus and set it back with default on blur

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#<%=Txt_search.ClientID%>')
    .focus(function(){  
      if($(this).val()=='Group Name..')
      {
         $(this).val('');
      }
  })
   .blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).val('Group Name..');
            }
        });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ekR2w/)**

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do that easily using jQuery something like below.

```
    $('#<%=Txt_search.ClientID%>').click(function() {
         $(this).val("");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using asp.net webforms, i think you'll be better off using the [AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/) specifically the TextBoxWaterMarkExtender control.

See sample code below.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBox1_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" 
                    runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
                    WatermarkText="Group Name ...">
                </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
```