# How to clear a textbox when clicking inside textbox using asp.net vb code

Tags: asp.net

I am using 2.0 .Net framework. How to clear the text inside the text box when user clicks inside the text box to enter the keyword to userid?

Comment: This can be done using javascript or jQuery. look at this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023135/how-to-clear-a-textbox-onfocus

Answer (score 0):

Please add the ajax control tool kit and add watermark

`<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBox1_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" 
                    runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
                    WatermarkText="YOUR TEXT ...">
                </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>`

Comment: HOW TO ADD ajax control tool kit and whether it works for .net 2.0 framework

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

html

```
<label for="one">Input one</label>
<input id="one" type="text" />
<label for="two">Input two</label>
<input id="two" type="text" value="" />
```

Jquery :

```
$('input:text').each(
    function(i,el) {
        if (!el.value || el.value == '') {
            el.placeholder = 'placeholdertext';
            /* or:
            el.placeholder = $('label[for=' + el.id + ']').text();
            */
        }
    });
```

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LAfN2/)

Comment: hi Ramesh where should I write j query whether I write it in html page I have 2 textboxes one is username and another one is password how can I do for these 2 textboxes please help me